# Gitlab CI: Using "environment" key with trigger in job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am looking to use the environment keyword as shown below in job which has trigger.

```
deploy:
 stage: deploy 
 environment:
   name: develop     
 variables:    
   ENV: develop    
 trigger:         
   include:
     - local: '<path to pipeline config>'
```

However, it is giving error **"config contains unknown keys: environment"**

It is working fine using "script" instead of trigger. Anyway it works with trigger ?

Comment: Found the same issue reported in gitlab the other day - https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/350550. Hope it will be resolved

Answer (score 6):

Yes apparently thats not allowed. I also felt this error and was expecting the environment config to be applicable on the child pipeline like below

```
sit-pipeline:
  trigger:
    include:
      - local: pipeline/sit-pipeline.yaml
  stage: deploy
  when: manual
  needs: ["sit-approval"]
  environment:
    name: sit
    url: http://sanjay-sit.com
```

But this gives an error This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: sit-pipeline config contains unknown keys: environment.

It would have been a good feature especially when we want to put some approval process and protect the environment.

Comment: this is not a solution to the issue. The answer from @tporeba is.

Answer (score 5):

Probably nothing you can do for child (same project) pipelines, but if somebody is looking for a solution for multi-project pipelines (like I was), then you can do the trigger via the API from `script` block.

This way of triggering is almost identical to using `trigger` keyword, AFAIK the only difference is that there is no `strategy` option, so you would have to implement necessary behavior yourself.

The good news is that GitLab notices the relation between upstream and downstream pipelines called via API and shows this in GUI. Another advantage is that you can retry such jobs, unlike trigger jobs. So this integrates nicely with [Environments and Deployments feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/).

See also the docs:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html#trigger-a-multi-project-pipeline-by-using-the-api
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/

Answer (score 0):

Check [GitLab 16.4](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/09/22/gitlab-16-4-released/#support-for-environment-keyword-in-downstream-pipelines) (September 2023) can help:

> ### Support for environment keyword in downstream pipelines
>
> If you need to trigger a downstream pipeline from a CI/CD pipeline job, you can use the `trigger` keyword.
>
> To enhance your deployment management, you can now specify an environment with the `environment` keyword when you use `trigger`.
> For example, you might trigger a downstream pipeline for the `main` branch on your `/web-app` project with environment name `dev` and a specified environment URL.
>
> Previously, when you ran separate pipelines for CI and CD and used the `trigger` keyword to start the CD pipeline, specifying environment details was not possible. This made it hard to track deployments from your CI project. Adding support for environments simplifies deployment tracking across projects.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html#downstream-pipelines-for-deployments) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/369061).

Answer (score -1):

You can't set environment on bridge jobs. You must set `environment.name` on the triggered job in the included config. E.g., in `pipeline/sit-pipeline.yaml`